# How to send a small amount of data to a large amount of iPhones

Tags: ios, tcp, udp

What kind of protocols can I use to send data from a server (php) to iPhones?

I ruled out UDP because on cellular, iPhones don't keep any ports open for outside communication (for obvious reasons). And TCP is too data hungry. I'm trying to find an in between that uses minimal data and doesn't tax infrastructure.

I'm first doing an API call to get information - then at this point, I want the iPhones to "listen" for data. Then my server will send data to all the phones that are listening.

Any thoughts on how to go about doing this? Or is this kind of connection impossible?

Comment: How "small" is the data?

Comment: It's 8 characters. Not sure how that converts to bytes.

Comment: If your data is so small, you can use Apple's push notification service.

Comment: But I don't want the data to go to the user. I want it to go to the app.

Comment: Well, if you do not include a sound name, a badge count or a title, the user will not see it, but your app will receive it if it is in the foreground.

Comment: REALLY? Whoa. That might be what I need.... What's the reliability of push notifications?

Comment: Not 100%. Apple says you shouldn't rely on push payloads for critical data because there are no guarantees. How critical is your data? Also take into account that users could disable push notifications for your app. This is why I answered in comment - not sure if it fits your need.

Comment: Well what APN offers is EXACTLY what I want. But note that all devices will be active and have service. Does that increase its chances of delivery? It's relatively critical. I suppose I could send it twice.

Comment: know anything about delivery time? I need within 20 seconds MAX

Comment: From experience, push notifications arrive within 0.5-2 seconds of sending and are very reliable if you manage sending correctly. When sending a push notification, Apple exposes an API to check if you should continue sending to that device (read their doc for more info). If you follow the rules and are careful, you are first tier sender and payloads arrive very fast and reliably. But they can't guarantee it.

Comment: Let me know if I should add it as answer so you can accept.

Comment: YES DEFINETELY ADD AN ANSWER. THIS IS AMAZING. you've made my night. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, one solution is to use the Apple Push Notifications Service.

More info here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html